# How to attach .amr file to mail in Android

Tags: android, email-attachments

I want to attach amr file in attachment but i am unable to attach.
My code is as follows:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri U = Uri.parse(path of amr file);
        //System.out.println("uri is:" + U);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
        " from ..");
        emailIntent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ""
                + "\n" + "\n" + "Through application name");

        emailIntent.setType("audio/rfc822");

        //emailIntent.setType("audio/*");
        // emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,U);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
        ""));
```

i have used **emailIntent.setType("audio/rfc822") , emailIntent.setType("audio/*"); and emailIntent.setType("audio/amr")**; but no luck

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does _but no luck_ mean.? Does it give any error. BTW, what is the path of audio file. If it is in the internal storage, then you are really unlucky.

Comment: no luck means i get message no attachment could be load.. Audio file is in SDCard

Comment: can you show the path of the **.amr** file.?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Songs/"+SongActivity.songname

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using,

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
```

**Activity Action:** Deliver multiple data to someone else.